# Putting a framebox around enumerated items

Tags: org-export, latex

I would like to put my enumerated items in a framebox with rounded corners. I can do it with LaTex. But I would like to do it in emacs org document. How can I do it ?

Comment: Generally speaking, you have to add the LaTeX markup to your org-mode file by quoting it appropriately - see e.g. [this section of the manual](https://orgmode.org/manual/Quoting-LaTeX-code.html#Quoting-LaTeX-code). If you run into trouble, edit your question and add a small example in LaTeX; someone might be able to tell you how to write that example in org mode.

Comment: The manual has some info on choosing LaTeX environments for specific lists: https://orgmode.org/manual/Plain-lists-in-LaTeX-export.html#Plain-lists-in-LaTeX-export -- I'd hoped to find how to customise the LaTeX generated for all lists so you could amend that somehow but didn't find it on a quick search.

Comment: To add to my comment above, you can probably do for all lists with export filters (https://orgmode.org/manual/Advanced-Export-Configuration.html#Advanced-Export-Configuration) but the details are beyond a quick solution from me, but maybe that's a pointer for someone else.